# YouTube Data API some videos do not return channel

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-channels

I use the YouTube Data API to get some information from a query result (videos).

The most videos return their data correct. But some videos don't return their channel title (all other fields return correct anyway).

```
    com.google.api.services.youtube.YouTube.Search.List search = youtube.search().list("id,snippet");
    search.setKey(getString(R.string.APIKEYYOUTUBE));
    search.setQ("hi");
    search.setType("video");
    search.setFields("items(id/kind,id/videoId,snippet/title,snippet/thumbnails/medium/url,snippet/channelTitle,snippet/publishedAt)");
    search.setMaxResults(7);

        [...]

    String vId = rId.getVideoId();
    String test = singleVideo.getSnippet().getChannelTitle();
```

Example:

Second video returned:

```
vId = "Kgw9xKQX-dI"
test = "htmailru"
```

Third video returned :

```
vId = "Q_6XNufgvA4"
test = ""
```

But if I proof the third video ID in youtube it has (as expected) a channel title.

Any ideas?

Comment: It seems you're having problems to read special chars, quotes and so on, cause they can scape the string you're building. A workaround for this would be Apache Commons IO library or Guava, not shure. Luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this issue was reported almost two years ago, but unfortunately there hasn't yet been a response from Google.  The reporter indicated that `channelTitle` returned blank whenever the channel title included a space.  (In your example, the channel title for Q_6XNufgvA4 is "World's Best Videos," which indeed includes a space.)

https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=6104

Fortunately, as a workaround, `channelTitle` does appear to populate correctly when returned from [`videos.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) and [`channels.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list).

**videos.list:**

Using `videoId` from the search response

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&
id=Q_6XNufgvA4&
fields=items%2Fsnippet%2FchannelTitle&
key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

returns

```
{
 "items": [
  {
   "snippet": {
    "channelTitle": "World's Best Videos"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

**channels.list:**

You can get `channelId` from your search response (`items/snippet/channelId`) and send a request as follows.

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet&
id=UCHqBLGGOvojeQswyJptjukA&
fields=items%2Fsnippet%2Ftitle&
key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

returns

```
{
 "items": [
  {
   "snippet": {
    "title": "World's Best Videos"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked proper. I use this way only for videos which return "". Sadly this way costs more time and api units (from the available 50,000,000). Hope a fix will come.